# How can I change my Iterator to be a Fast-fail Iterator?

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator, singly-linked-list, fail-fast

I'm trying to understand how to modify the *Iterator* of my *Linked List* to be fail-fast.

I understand what it means for an Iterator to be fail-fast, but I don't know how exactly should I change my implementation to achieve this behavior.

I was thinking about adding a key so for every add, but I don't think it is good enough. It is the first time I'm trying to implement a fail-fast iterator, and I would really appreciate any hint.

*My code:*

```
package GenericLinkedList;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class GenericLinkedList<E> implements Iterable<E> {
    private Node<E> head;

    public void pushFront(E data){
        head = new Node<>(data, head);
    }

    public E popFront(){
        E dataHead = head.data;
        head = head.next;

        return dataHead;
    }

    public int size(){
        int counter = 0;

        for(E element : this){
            ++counter;
        }

        return counter;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return (null == head);
    }

    public Iterator<E> find(E data){
        IteratorIMP iter = new IteratorIMP(head);

        for(E element : this){
            if(element.equals(data)){
                return iter;
            }
            iter.next();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static <E> GenericLinkedList<E> merge(GenericLinkedList<E> firstList, GenericLinkedList<E> secondList){
        GenericLinkedList<E> mergeList = new GenericLinkedList<E>();

        for(E element : firstList){
            mergeList.pushFront(element);
        }

        for(E element : secondList){
            mergeList.pushFront(element);
        }

        return newReverse(mergeList);
    }

    public static <E> GenericLinkedList<E> newReverse(GenericLinkedList<E> list){
        GenericLinkedList<E> reverseList = new GenericLinkedList<E>();

        for(E element : list){
            reverseList.pushFront(element);
        }

        return reverseList;
    }

    private static class Node<T> {
        private Node<T> next;
        private T data;

        private Node(T data, Node<T> next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    private class IteratorIMP implements Iterator<E> {

        Node<E> node;

        private IteratorIMP(Node<E> start){
            node = start;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (node != null);
        }

        @Override
        public E next() {
            E data = node.data;
            node = node.next;

            return data;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        IteratorIMP iter = new IteratorIMP(head);

        return iter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fail-fast implementation of the `Iterator` insures that it would raise an exception if there's an evidence that the collection is being structurally modified (*an element was added or removed*) during the iteration process, because in such a case, iterator might not be able to reflect the actual state of the collection.

The common approach is to introduce two *counters of modifications*:

- one as the instance field of the list `modCount`, which would be incremented whenever list gets modified via `pushFront()`, `popFront()`, etc.
- another in the `Iterator` - `expectedModCount`.

If during the `next()` call turns out that `modCount` and `expectedModCount` variables are not equal, that means that there has been a modification after the iterator was created. In such a case, fail-fast Iterators from the JDK would throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

```
public class GenericLinkedList<E> implements Iterable<E> {
    private Node<E> head;
    private int modCount;
    
    public void pushFront(E data) {
        modCount++; // list is being modified - incrementing the count
        head = new Node<>(data, head);
    }
    
    public E popFront() {
        modCount++; // list is being modified - incrementing the count
        E dataHead = head.data;
        head = head.next;
        
        return dataHead;
    }
    
    // ...
    
    private class IteratorIMP implements Iterator<E> {
        
        private Node<E> node;
        private final int expectedModCount;
        
        private IteratorIMP(Node<E> start) {
            this.node = start;
            this.expectedModCount = GenericLinkedList.this.modCount;
        }
        
        // ...
        
        @Override
        public E next() {
            if (expectedModCount != modCount) {
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            }
            
            E data = node.data;
            node = node.next;
            
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```